# ccmake. in cygwin & Windows 7 (64bit)

Tags: windows, cygwin

I have only used Mac in the past to compile, so I am a little lost with the following issue.

I am trying to compile a program in Windows 7 through cygwin. Svn co to get the source code works, but upon $ ccmake. the error "command not found" appears. I have the devel. tools from the cygwin setup, as well as cmake and MinGW-64 installed. Where can be the bug? Is ccmake. command supported at all in cygwin?

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Cygwin, you should install Cmake using Cygwin as well. The package should be called "cmake". Once that is done you should find ccmake at

```
/usr/bin/ccmake
```

AKA

```
C:\cygwin\bin\ccmake.exe
```

and you should make sure your `PATH` contains `/usr/bin`

[**ref**](http://cygwin.com/packages/cmake/cmake-2.8.9-2)

Comment: Hello!
Thank you for the reply. 
cmake is already installed (via cygwin setup) and the path is also in the environment variables. 
I wonder though - I also have Cmake 2.8 installed (with path specified as well) - could there be a conflict`?